# R How to reshape wider table with multiple columns into longer table with multiple variables

Tags: r, tidyr

My database contains 2 measurement periods on the same monitoring plots. On each monitoring plot we measure the volume and area of deadwood and number of tree species regeneration rejuvenated on deadwood. The deadwood is divided into 3 degrees of decomposition. I need to convert wider table to a longer one.
After reading many posts here I am almost sure that the solution is in the tidyr package and pivot_longer function. I will be very grateful for your help.

[picture of dw_wider table and dw_longer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8rzJ.png)

**here is the code for wider table:**

```
dw_wider <- structure(list(Period = c(
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L),
DwType = c(
"1_trunks", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "2_stumps"), 
Plot = c(
101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L), 
m3ha_dc1 = c(
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
m3ha_dc2 = c(
185.9886004, 
36.14392074, 13.09592051, 61.99620013, 12.04797358, 4.365306836, 
399.9427251, 187.306535, 59.38662, 133.3142417, 62.43551166, 
19.79554), 
m3ha_dc3 = c(
0.160849544, 16.04894292, 10.76337767, 
0.053616515, 5.349647639, 3.587792556, 75.0880521, 27.88578286, 
32.00025432, 25.0293507, 9.295260953, 10.66675144), 
m2ha_dc1 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), m2ha_dc2 = c(669.9940464, 
255.4172853, 147.8409739, 167.4985116, 63.85432132, 36.96024346, 
1697.643681, 734.7850821, 303.60205, 424.4109202, 183.6962705, 
75.9005125), 
m2ha_dc3 = c(
0.40212386, 74.99540121, 87.88647158, 
0.100530965, 18.7488503, 21.97161789, 297.8308267, 148.4095964, 
132.5277239, 74.45770669, 37.10239909, 33.13193096), 
pcsm2_dc1 = c(
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
pcsm2_dc2 = c(
0.895530346, 0, 0, 0, 0.326626119, 0.065875708, 1.432848553, 0, 0, 0, 0.544376866, 0.263502832), 
pcsm2_dc3 = c(
0, 0, 12.06101441, 0, 1.212859575, 0.30182364, 0, 0, 18.20530477, 0, 2.1561948, 0.60364728)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

**and here is the result I want to achieve**:

```
dw_longer <- structure(list(Period = c(
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
DwType = c(
"1_trunks", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "2_stumps"), 
    Plot = c(
101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 03L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L), 
dc = c(
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
m3ha = c(
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 185.9886004, 36.14392074, 13.09592051, 61.99620013, 12.04797358, 4.365306836, 399.9427251, 187.306535, 59.38662, 133.3142417, 62.43551166, 19.79554, 0.160849544, 16.04894292, 10.76337767, 0.053616515, 5.349647639, 3.587792556, 75.0880521, 27.88578286, 32.00025432, 25.0293507, 9.295260953, 10.66675144), 
m2ha = c(
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 669.9940464, 255.4172853, 147.8409739, 167.4985116, 63.85432132, 36.96024346, 1697.643681, 734.7850821, 303.60205, 424.4109202, 183.6962705, 75.9005125, 0.40212386, 74.99540121, 87.88647158, 0.100530965, 18.7488503, 21.97161789, 297.8308267, 148.4095964, 132.5277239, 
74.45770669, 37.10239909, 33.13193096), 
pcsha = c(
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.895530346, 0, 0, 0, 0.326626119, 
0.065875708, 1.432848553, 0, 0, 0, 0.544376866, 0.263502832, 0, 0, 12.06101441, 0, 1.212859575, 0.30182364, 0, 0, 18.20530477, 0, 2.1561948, 0.60364728)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dw_wider <- structure(list(Period = c(
  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
  2L, 2L, 2L
), DwType = c(
  "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "2_stumps",
  "2_stumps", "2_stumps", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "1_trunks", "2_stumps",
  "2_stumps", "2_stumps"
), Plot = c(
  101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L,
  103L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 101L, 102L, 103L
), m3ha_dc1 = c(
  0L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), m3ha_dc2 = c(
  185.9886004,
  36.14392074, 13.09592051, 61.99620013, 12.04797358, 4.365306836,
  399.9427251, 187.306535, 59.38662, 133.3142417, 62.43551166,
  19.79554
), m3ha_dc3 = c(
  0.160849544, 16.04894292, 10.76337767,
  0.053616515, 5.349647639, 3.587792556, 75.0880521, 27.88578286,
  32.00025432, 25.0293507, 9.295260953, 10.66675144
), m2ha_dc1 = c(
  0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), m2ha_dc2 = c(
  669.9940464,
  255.4172853, 147.8409739, 167.4985116, 63.85432132, 36.96024346,
  1697.643681, 734.7850821, 303.60205, 424.4109202, 183.6962705,
  75.9005125
), m2ha_dc3 = c(
  0.40212386, 74.99540121, 87.88647158,
  0.100530965, 18.7488503, 21.97161789, 297.8308267, 148.4095964,
  132.5277239, 74.45770669, 37.10239909, 33.13193096
), pcsm2_dc1 = c(
  0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), pcsm2_dc2 = c(
  0.895530346,
  0, 0, 0, 0.326626119, 0.065875708, 1.432848553, 0, 0, 0, 0.544376866,
  0.263502832
), pcsm2_dc3 = c(
  0, 0, 12.06101441, 0, 1.212859575,
  0.30182364, 0, 0, 18.20530477, 0, 2.1561948, 0.60364728
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -12L
)) 

dw_wider |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(Period, Plot, DwType), names_pattern = "(.*)_dc(.+)", names_to = c("col", "dc")) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value) |> 
  arrange(dc, Period, Plot, DwType)
#> # A tibble: 36 × 7
#>    Period DwType    Plot dc     m3ha  m2ha pcsm2
#>     <int> <chr>    <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1      1 1_trunks   101 1         0     0     0
#>  2      1 2_stumps   101 1         0     0     0
#>  3      1 1_trunks   102 1         0     0     0
#>  4      1 2_stumps   102 1         0     0     0
#>  5      1 1_trunks   103 1         0     0     0
#>  6      1 2_stumps   103 1         0     0     0
#>  7      2 1_trunks   101 1         0     0     0
#>  8      2 2_stumps   101 1         0     0     0
#>  9      2 1_trunks   102 1         0     0     0
#> 10      2 2_stumps   102 1         0     0     0
#> # … with 26 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The code works very well but it is necessary to replace "|>" by "%>%".

Comment: You can use `%>%` (from the magrittr package) instead of `|>`. `|>` is in newer versions of R, so won't work in older versions.